# media queries working but not correctly

Tags: mobile, media, tablet

I'm having a bit of an issue. I have built a responsive site at http://www.nickpassaro.com/ClientSiteDev/New-NPD/ but for some reason, while it works perfectly on the desktop and rearranges its layout properly when you resize the browser window, it isn't working right on mobile devices. On the iPhone, its sending me to the tablet site, and on windows phone 8, it is showing me the mobile site but everything looks really zoomed out. My media queries are set to use under 640px for mobile, under 960 for tablet, and over 960 for desktop. Can someone hit view source on my site and see if they can see why it's using device pixels rather than CSS pixels?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason its not working properly is that you have not assigned the Viewport.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

a basic viewport for your case can be:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out. I've rebuilt this site 3 times so far, and I don't recall if I used the view port tag on all of them by I must have. The thing is I copied the header of this site from a responsive site that worked, and so maybe I missed that meta tag when I copied my old header into this new site

Comment: It worked gloriously. I can't believe I forgot that meta tag lol